# dynamic image is not loading on mobile - Angular

Tags: angular, image, mobile

I have been trying to load a dynamic image on my website, but it only works on my computer browser.
If I open the site using a smartphone, the image will not load.

```
<div class="d-inline-block">
   <img class="d-inline" 
        src="http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/{{ 
        weather.icon }}@2x.png" alt="weather"
    />
   <span class="main_description">{{ weather.short_climate_desc }}, 
   </span>
   <span class="detailed_description">{{ weather.detail_climate_desc }}
   </span>
</div>
```

Before it was load correctly, but after I implemented this function I notice the error.

HOME.COMPONENT.TS

```
getGeoLocation() {
    if(navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((geoPosition) => {
        this.weatherService.getInitialLocation(geoPosition.coords.latitude, geoPosition.coords.longitude)
        .subscribe(data => {
          this.changeBG(this.dayOrNight(
            this.pegue_data_local(data.timezone),
            this.pegue_nascer_e_por_do_sol(data.timezone, data.sys.sunrise),
            this.pegue_nascer_e_por_do_sol(data.timezone, data.sys.sunset)))

          this.weather = new Weather
            (
              data.name,
              data.sys.country,
              new Date(this.pegue_data_local(data.timezone)),
              data.weather[0].icon,
              data.weather[0].main,
              data.weather[0].description,
              Math.round(data.main.temp),
              this.meterSecondTokmHour(data.wind.speed),
              this.getWindDirection(data.wind.deg),
              data.main.humidity,
              Math.round(data.main.feels_like),
              data.main.pressure,
              Math.round(data.main.temp_min),
              Math.round(data.main.temp_max),
              this.meterToKm(data.visibility),
              new Date(this.pegue_nascer_e_por_do_sol(data.timezone, data.sys.sunrise)),
              new Date(this.pegue_nascer_e_por_do_sol(data.timezone, data.sys.sunset))
            )
          this.displayInfo = true;

        }, (err) => { this.error2 = true; this.error = false; })
      }, (error)=> {
        console.log(error.message);
      })
    }
  }
```

WEATHERSERVICE.ts

```
  getInitialLocation(lat: number, lon: number): Observable<any> {
    console.log(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&appid=${this.apiKey}`);
    return this.http.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}${this.unit}&appid=${this.apiKey}`);
  }
```

I am calling this function on my ngOnInit().
When the site loads, it gets the user location, search and return weather information for that specific location and creates an object.

Obs: all other informations are been displayed, BUT image.
Obs: This problem only happen on mobile devices, the image loads correctly on regular web browsers.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was the problem.
I just had to add and "s" at the end of the image link.
instead of http I used https.

I hope this can help others.

```
<div class="d-inline-block">
   <img *ngIf="weather && weather.icon" class="d-inline" 
    src="https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/{{ 
    weather.icon }}@2x.png" alt="weather"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be got to do with css and hidden xs? If you resize your browser down to mobile width is it still visible?

Comment: No... I already checked this... if I resize my browser nada select mobile it shows normally. Only mobile devices are not loading... I only get the alt=“” attribute from img tag.

Answer (score 0):

Can your try this and see what displays. I think the icon is blank and that would explain why the alt text is appearing because it cannot find the path to the image

```
<div class="d-inline-block">
   <img *ngIf="weather && weather.icon" class="d-inline" 
    src="http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/{{ 
    weather.icon }}@2x.png" alt="weather"
/>
<span>weather.icon = {{weather.icon}}</span>
<span class="main_description">{{ weather.short_climate_desc }}, 
</span>
<span class="detailed_description">{{ weather.detail_climate_desc }}
</span>
```

And console.log(this.weather) to see the value on your desktop and you can display this on the mobile to get all it fields

```
<span>{{this.weather | json}}</span>
```

Comment: As soon as the app starts I get the user's location and display the weather information for that location. For this feature to work, user have to allow the browser to get location.
If user ALLOW location, the image does not load. even if he tries to search other city.

if user DOESN'T ALLOW, it will not get any information, if the user search another city it will load the image.